# How to Keep an OAuth Session Alive

Tags: api, oauth, kohana, instagram

Problem: I'm working with the Instagram Api and am Authenticating with OAuth. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to keep my session alive. Eventually it will expire and am no longer to grab photos from the service.

Background: I have created a settings page in my custom admin panel that accpets the Client ID and Client Secret. It saves these values into my DB and my app uses them to connect to the Api. I have a button that you click "Save and Connect", which updates my DB, and then requests the auth tokens from the Instagram Api. All of this works great.

I Need: to keep the session alive indefinitely or as long as possible. I am caching the result set from the api, so i don't make too many requests and my access token is stored in php session. However, when a new user visits, and doesn't have this token in their session, after cache expires and session expires, the photos will no longer be available?

Look forward to hearing some possible solutions. Please let me know if you require more information or if my question is in any way unclear.

Thanks,

Zack

Comment: Can't you just request a new token for the Instagram Client when the token has expired?

Comment: I can, but I believe this would send the user back to my redirect uri, which is in the admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save  the most recent access token in a DB or on the server, and make the requests with the saved token.  Instagram access tokens are long-lived (for now at least).  Feel free to use the wrapper I have [here](https://github.com/cdbconcepts/InstaWrapper).  That way sessions are a non-issue except for the first time you get a token.

```
  $insta = new Instagram(array(
                'client_id' => $client_id,
                'client_secret' => $secret,
                'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri
            ));

if(!$insta->isAuthenticated()){
            /* Not logged in */
            $login_url = $this->insta->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope' => $scope,
            ));
            header("Location: ".$login_url.");
        }


/* Save the token */
if($this->insta->getToken())
{
    $token_to_save = $this->insta->getToken();
}
```

Then use the saved token:

```
$ig_saved_token = getTokenFromDBSomewhere();    
$insta->setToken($ig_saved_token); // Set the saved token
$r = $insta->api('users/self/media/recent'); // Request works with saved token!
```